# Vue v-for object does not update after data changed

Tags: vue.js

I use vue version 2.5.x

Example like below.

No matter how hard I click "add item" the button, no item show in page.

But the "add item version 2" works!

Add `:key` won't help. What is the problem?

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: {},
    count: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.items[this.count.toString()] = this.count;
      this.count++;
      console.log(this.items);
    },
    add2() {
      let items = {}
      items[this.count.toString()] = this.count;
      this.items = items;
      this.count++;
      console.log(this.items);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="add">add item</button>
  <button @click="add2">add item version 2</button>
  <p v-for="(item, key) in items" :keys="item">{{item}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace : **this.items[this.count.toString()] = this.count;**

with **Vue.set(this.items,this.count.toString(),this.count);**

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: {},
    count: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
        Vue.set(this.items,this.count.toString(),this.count);

      this.count++;
      console.log(this.items);
    },
    add2() {
      let items = {}
      items[this.count.toString()] = this.count;
      this.items = items;
      this.count++;
      console.log(this.items);
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zbb57ozv/

It's a **limitations of javascript or Vue js caveat** . check out section **Change Detection Caveats** of **vue document** for more information : [Vue-Js Reactivity In Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)