# Vue doesn't update DOM upon 'indirectly' changing the value of an expression

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**TL;DR**

I am trying to dynamically build a UI from JSON. The JSON represents a vue.js app with application state (variables) & UI building logic conditional on those variables.

The JSON object of `"type": "switch"` (see the fiddle linked below), directs the vue.js app to display one of many `"cases": {"case1": {..}, "case2": {..}}` depending on the value of a state variable `"variable": "key" /*translates to vueApp.key */`.

Changing one of the variables (`update_status`) leads to DOM update initially. Changing it again after mounting the app does not affect the DOM, sadly. I'm pretty sure I am doing something stupid or missing something subtle.

---

**Slightly longer version**:

(If you're still reading this, [please look at the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/104139/) at this point. None of the below will make sense without it. Thanks!)

*Vue.js Template* (with `app.variables.update_status = "available"`)

```html
<script type="text/x-template" id="template-switch">
  <div>
      <!-- Debug statements -->
      Switch cases: {{data.cases}}<br>
      Variables: {{$root.variables}}


      <div v-for="(value, key) in data.cases">
          <div v-bind:class="$root.variables[data.variable]"
               v-if="key == $root.variables[data.variable]">
              <all-components v-bind:data="value"></all-components>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

*Input JSON* (bound as `data` in the above template):

```js
{
    // Switch on value of app.variables.update_status
    "type": "switch",
    "variable": "update_status",   // Refers to app.variables.update_status
                                   // Used in <script id="template-switch">
    "cases": {
        // if app.variables.update_status == "checking" (Initial value)
        "checking": {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "text": "Checking for updates"
        },
        // if app.variables.update_status == "available" (Changed below)
        "available": {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "text": "Updates available."
        }
    }
}
```

**My question:**

Assuming `app` is the Vue.js app, I'd expect setting `app.variables.update_status = "available"` should lead to DOM change. But it doesn't as described in TL;DR section. I'm hoping to understand why.

**What I have tried**:

- Made the app watch the entire hierarchy under the object.
- I initially thought this is because Vue is unable to monitor `object[key]` expression where key can change. [But its definitely able to do it.](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/104119/)
- Last value set before mounting the app shows up. After the app is mounted, any change to the the variable sticks but doesn't trigger DOM update. (Annotated with "Doesn't work!" in the fiddle.)

**Try it out!**

Here's the **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/104139/)** (heavily downsized, and commented for easier understanding :))

**What to try:**

Once the fiddle runs, open the browser console and try executing the following statements:

- `DEBUG.variables.update_status = "available";`
- `DEBUG.variables.update_status = "checking";`

Vue.js version: 2.5.16

---

### Update

Also, I just found out that if I pass data object as:

```
new Vue({.., data: { .. , variables: {update_status: "temp"}}})
```

– it works!

I don’t understand this, primarily because variables field is set up to have a deep watcher. I’d assume that when it would have a its fields updated (such as `variables.update_status = "new-value";)`, the observer would eventually trigger the DOM update. But for some reason this doesn’t happen.

I’m really hoping I’m doing something stupid, and that this isn’t this a bug.

Link to the new Fiddle that shows this behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/g0z3xcyk/

Comment: In the second fiddle, you're setting the `update_status` property when you instance `Vue`, in the first one you don't. And [vue can't detect property addition or deletion](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

Comment: check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhgyje52/), as @LuisOrduz said, Vue can't detect property addition or deletion. that is why first fiddle didn't work. so one solution is decalre it first as your second fiddle did, another solution is uses `Vue.set` or `vm.$set`. Then you didn't need use JQUERY to append the $el to target dom object, just uses `app.$mount(selector)`.

Comment: Yep, another variation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143631/vue-v-for-object-does-not-update-after-data-changed (hopefully I will find a more canonical answer…). A more simple fiddle with just that change (using `Vue.set`), and a button for interactivity: https://jsfiddle.net/xo7rhpec/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it won't update in your first fiddle is because Vue doesn't detect property addition or deletion, and you're not passing the `update_status` property when you instance vue, [the docs explain it further](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

In your second fiddle you're setting `update_status` when you instance vue and that's why changes, in that case, are detected.

Another option, as mentioned in the docs, is using `Vue.set` or recreating the object entirely by assigning it again with `Object.assign`

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll test it when I get home. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Some issues with your code**:

1. Check [Reactivity In depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked) as @LuisOrduz commented & answered, **Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion**. so two solutions:
   decalare it first (as your second fiddle did), or uses `Vue.set` or `vm.$set` to add one property.
2. Use `vm.$mount(selector)` instead of using JQuery to append `vm.$el`; check [vm.$mount](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount)
3. It's better to use `vm.$data` to access data property instead of `vm[key]`; check [vm.$data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data)

**Below is one demo**:

```js
function registerComponents() {
    Vue.component('all-components', {
      template: '#template-all-components',
      props: ['data']
    });
    Vue.component('weave-switch', {
      template: '#template-switch',
      props: ['data'],
      methods: {
        toggleStatus: function () {
          this.$root.$data.variables.update_status += ' @'
        }
      }
    });
    Vue.component('paragraph', {
      template: '#template-paragraph',
      props: ['data']
    });
}

function GenericCard(selector, options) {
    var data = Object.assign({}, options.data, {variables: {}});
    var watch = {};
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
        watch[key] = {handler: function(val) {
        }, deep: true};
    });
    var app = new Vue({
        template: options.template,
        data: function () { // uses function instead
            return data
        },
        watch: watch
    });
    
    DEBUG = app;

    return {
        load: function(data) {
            Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
                app.$data[key] = data[key];
            });
            
            //app.$data.variables.update_status = "checking"; // orginal method
            
                        app.$set(app.$data.variables, 'update_status', 'checking') // new solution
            app.$mount(selector);
            
            //var dom = app.$el;
            //$(selector).append(dom); // uses vm.$mount(selector) instead
            
            DEBUG.$set(DEBUG.$data.variables, 'update_status', 'available')  // new solution
            //DEBUG.$data.variables.update_status = 'available1'  // or new solution
            //DEBUG.variables.update_status = "available";  // orginal method
        },
        DEBUG: DEBUG
    };
}

registerComponents();

card = GenericCard('#app', {
  template: "#template-card",
  data: {
    ui: {}
  }
});
card.load({
        ui: {
      // Switch on value of app.variables.update_status
      "type": "switch",
      "variable": "update_status",   // Refers to app.variables.update_status
                                     // Used in <script id="template-switch">
            "cases": {
        // if app.variables.update_status == "checking" (Initial value)
        "checking": {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "text": "Checking for updates"
        },
        // if app.variables.update_status == "available" (Changed below)
        "available": {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "text": "Updates available."
        }
      }
    }
  });
Vue.config.productionTip = false

function toggleStatus() {
  card.DEBUG.$data.variables.update_status += ' #'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="template-all-components">
  <div v-if="data.type == 'paragraph'">
      <paragraph v-bind:data="data.text"></paragraph>
  </div>
  <div v-else-if="data.type == 'switch'">
      <weave-switch v-bind:data="data"></weave-switch>
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="template-switch">
  <div>
        <!-- Debug statements -->
      Switch cases: {{data.cases}}<br>
      Variables: {{$root.variables}}
      <button @click="toggleStatus()">Toggle</button>
      
      <div v-for="(value, key) in data.cases">
          <div v-bind:class="$root.$data.variables[data.variable]"
               v-if="key == $root.$data.variables[data.variable]">
              <all-components v-bind:data="value"></all-components>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="template-paragraph">
  <p>{{data}}</p>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="template-card">
  <all-components v-bind:data="ui"></all-components>
</script>


<div id="app">
  
</div>

<button onclick="toggleStatus()">Toggle2</button>
```